# Why is the it wrong to use a if-else statement choose which fragment to start

Tags: android-fragments

I am quite new to app android programming. My app crashes when I used a if-else block to select either start the Register User fragment or the Main_Menu Fragment in the Start Activity (2).

Can anyone explain to me the reason behind this?

Here all my codes

1) User Class

```
package com.kkkcube3.pcn;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by User on 17/3/2015.
 */
public class User
{
    private String user_Name;
    private String user_Password = "1234PCN";
    private String user_Email;
    private int user_Tel;
    Context context;

    User()
    {
        user_Name = null;
        user_Email = null;
        user_Tel = 0;
    }

    User(String name,String password,String email,int tel)
    {
        user_Name = name;
        user_Password = password;
        user_Email = email;
        user_Tel = tel;
    }

    public void setUser_Name(String setUserName)
    {
        user_Name = setUserName;
    }

    public String getUser_Name(String valid_Password)
    {
        if (valid_Password != user_Password)
        {
            String invalid_Password = "Invalid Password, cannot execute your request";
            Toast.makeText(context,invalid_Password,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        else
        {
            return user_Name;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setUser_Password(String setUserPassword)
    {
        user_Password = setUserPassword;
    }

    public String getUser_Password(String valid_Password)
    {
        if (valid_Password != user_Password)
        {
            String invalid_Password = "Invalid Password, cannot execute your request";
            Toast.makeText(context,invalid_Password,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        else
        {
            return user_Password;
        }
        return  null;
    }

    public void setUser_Email(String setUserEmail)
    {
        user_Email = setUserEmail;
    }

    public String getUser_Email(String valid_Password)
    {
        if (valid_Password != user_Password)
        {
            String invalid_Password = "Invalid Password, cannot execute your request";
            Toast.makeText(context,invalid_Password,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        else
        {
            return user_Email;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setUser_Tel(int setUserTel)
    {
        user_Tel = setUserTel;
    }

    public int getUser_Tel(String valid_Password)
    {
        if (valid_Password != user_Password)
        {
            String invalid_Password = "Invalid Password, cannot execute your request";
            Toast.makeText(context,invalid_Password,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        else
        {
            return user_Tel;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void createUserFile()
    {

    }
}
```

2) Start Activity

```
package com.kkkcube3.pcn;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class Start extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static String default_Password ="1234PCN";
    User user = new User();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        user.setUser_Password("kkk");
        if(user.getUser_Password(default_Password)== default_Password)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, new Main_Menu_Fragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        if(user.getUser_Password(default_Password)!= default_Password)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, new Main_Menu_Fragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_start, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you indicate the error message?

However try this code:

Replace:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, new Main_Menu_Fragment())
                    .commit();
```

With:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Main_Menu_Fragment(), "MyTAG")
                    .commit();
```